# Average value of a waveform

Tags: electric-current

I was trying to find the average value of waveform but it came out to be negative.
The waveform was:
$$v(t)=\cases{2t&if $0<x<1$\\-4&if $1<x<2$}.$$
Can the average value of a waveform be negative?
If yes then what does it signify?

Comment: Waveform of what? Is $v$ a voltage? Voltages can be positive or negative. If the instantaneous value of something can be negative, the average value can be negative.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, v is a voltage.

Comment: @G.Smith what about the form factor can it also be negative??

Comment: What do you mean by “form factor”?

Comment: @G.Smith Form factor: Ratio of RMS voltage to Average Voltage

Answer (score 0):

Voltage itself is just difference, if the average $V_{AB}$ is positive then the associated $V_{BA}$ is negative, this holds for averages as well. Not only can the average of voltage be negative, but half of all voltages are.

In Engineering textbooks however, sometimes when they say average they are referring to RMS (root-mean-square), which is in fact always positive:

$${\displaystyle V_{\text{RMS}}=\lim _{T\rightarrow \infty }{\sqrt {{1 \over {2T}}{\int _{-T}^{T}{[V(t)]}^{2}\,dt}}}.}$$

The integrand in this case is always positive, and so is the integral, and of course so is the result of the square root, $V_{RMS}$ is always positive (only for real voltages). The exact same definition and consequences are true for current.